# Format table of contents in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

I can create a table of contents in beamer using  `\begin{frame}\frametitle{Outline} \tableofcontents \end{frame}`
which will lead to a list similar to enumerate, i.e.

1. first section
2. second section
   ...

How can I replace the automatic numbering 1,2 by A1, A2?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}


\begin{document}


  \begin{frame}

     \frametitle{Overview}
     \tableofcontents

  \end{frame}

\section{First section}

  \begin{frame}

     \frametitle{First section}

content ... 

  \end{frame}

\section{Second section}

   \begin{frame}

      \frametitle{Second section}

content ...

  \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: Below is the example. It might be specific to the theme Madrid: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First section}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{First section}
content ...
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Second section}
content ...
\end{frame}

\end{document}`

Comment: Please don't post your code in a comment. Instead, please edit your query and post the code where it can be pretty-printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `section in toc` template like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode%
  % prevents the period to be printed with the first/last section option
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
  \else
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
    A\inserttocsectionnumber.
  \fi\fi%
  \inserttocsection\par%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


  \begin{frame}

     \frametitle{Overview}
     \tableofcontents

  \end{frame}

\section{First section}

  \begin{frame}

     \frametitle{First section}

content ... 

  \end{frame}

\section{Second section}

   \begin{frame}

      \frametitle{Second section}

content ...

  \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]